# MailChimp Extension stop sync suddenly

Tags: php, database, mailchimp

I installed MailChimp for Magento 1.1.7 extension on my site Magento 1.9.1.0 and I have enabled the extension on scope view and default view and it started sync everything fine. The total customers and total products reach 208 and total orders reach 8 and stops. When I check AOE Scheduler, mailchimp_bulksync_ecommerce_data has stopped and "died" when was processing. So, when I tried to manually proccess it and got the following error:

```
a:4:{i:0;s:1861:"SELECT `e`.*, `price_index`.`price`, `price_index`.`tax_class_id`, `price_index`.`final_price`, IF(price_index.tier_price IS NOT NULL, LEAST(price_index.min_price, price_index.tier_price), price_index.min_price) AS `minimal_price`, `price_index`.`min_price`, `price_index`.`max_price`, `price_index`.`tier_price`, `at_qty`.`qty`, `at_backorders`.`backorders`, `at_category_id`.`category_id`, `product_attribute_name`.`value` AS `name`, `product_attribute_visibility`.`value` AS `visibility`, `product_attribute_description`.`value` AS `description` FROM `catalog_product_entity` AS `e`
INNER JOIN `catalog_product_website` AS `product_website` ON product_website.product_id = e.entity_id AND product_website.website_id = '1'
INNER JOIN `catalog_product_index_price` AS `price_index` ON price_index.entity_id = e.entity_id AND price_index.website_id = '1' AND price_index.customer_group_id = 0
LEFT JOIN `cataloginventory_stock_item` AS `at_qty` ON (at_qty.`product_id`=e.entity_id) AND (at_qty.stock_id=1)
LEFT JOIN `cataloginventory_stock_item` AS `at_backorders` ON (at_backorders.`product_id`=e.entity_id) AND (at_backorders.stock_id=1)
LEFT JOIN `catalog_category_product` AS `at_category_id` ON (at_category_id.`product_id`=e.entity_id)
INNER JOIN `catalog_product_entity_varchar` AS `product_attribute_name` ON e.entity_id = product_attribute_name.entity_id
INNER JOIN `catalog_product_entity_int` AS `product_attribute_visibility` ON e.entity_id = product_attribute_visibility.entity_id
INNER JOIN `catalog_product_entity_text` AS `product_attribute_description` ON e.entity_id = product_attribute_description.entity_id WHERE (product_attribute_name.attribute_id = '71') AND (product_attribute_visibility.attribute_id = '102') AND (product_attribute_description.attribute_id = '72') AND (`e`.`entity_id` IN()) GROUP BY `e`.`entity_id` LIMIT 100

";i:1;s:3358:"#0 /lib/Varien/Db/Statement/Pdo/Mysql.php(110): Zend_Db_Statement_Pdo->_execute(Array)
#1 /app/code/core/Zend/Db/Statement.php(291): Varien_Db_Statement_Pdo_Mysql->_execute(Array)
#2 /lib/Zend/Db/Adapter/Abstract.php(480): Zend_Db_Statement->execute(Array)
#3 /lib/Zend/Db/Adapter/Pdo/Abstract.php(238): Zend_Db_Adapter_Abstract->query('SELECT `e`.*, `...', Array)
#4 /lib/Varien/Db/Adapter/Pdo/Mysql.php(428): Zend_Db_Adapter_Pdo_Abstract->query('SELECT `e`.*, `...', Array)
#5 /lib/Zend/Db/Adapter/Abstract.php(737): Varien_Db_Adapter_Pdo_Mysql->query('SELECT `e`.*, `...', Array)
#6 /lib/Varien/Data/Collection/Db.php(740): Zend_Db_Adapter_Abstract->fetchAll('SELECT `e`.*, `...', Array)
#7 /app/code/core/Mage/Eav/Model/Entity/Collection/Abstract.php(1045): Varien_Data_Collection_Db->_fetchAll('SELECT `e`.*, `...')
#8 /app/code/core/Mage/Eav/Model/Entity/Collection/Abstract.php(871): Mage_Eav_Model_Entity_Collection_Abstract->_loadEntities(false, false)
#9 /lib/Varien/Data/Collection.php(741): Mage_Eav_Model_Entity_Collection_Abstract->load()
#10 /app/code/community/Ebizmarts/MailChimp/Model/Api/Products.php(80): Varien_Data_Collection->getIterator()
#11 /app/code/community/Ebizmarts/MailChimp/Model/Api/Products.php(49): Ebizmarts_MailChimp_Model_Api_Products->_buildNewProductRequest(Object(OrganicInternet_SimpleConfigurableProducts_Catalog_Model_Product), 'storeid-1_PRO_2...', '77eea787145de1d...', '1')
#12 /app/code/community/Ebizmarts/MailChimp/Model/Api/Batches.php(182): Ebizmarts_MailChimp_Model_Api_Products->createBatchJson('77eea787145de1d...', '1')
#13 /app/code/community/Ebizmarts/MailChimp/Model/Api/Batches.php(96): Ebizmarts_MailChimp_Model_Api_Batches->_sendEcommerceBatch('1')
#14 /app/code/community/Ebizmarts/MailChimp/Model/Cron.php(28): Ebizmarts_MailChimp_Model_Api_Batches->handleEcommerceBatches()
#15 [internal function]: Ebizmarts_MailChimp_Model_Cron->syncEcommerceBatchData(Object(Aoe_Scheduler_Model_Schedule))
#16 /app/code/community/Aoe/Scheduler/Model/Schedule.php(196): call_user_func_array(Array, Array)
#17 /app/code/community/Aoe/Scheduler/Model/Schedule.php(582): Aoe_Scheduler_Model_Schedule->runNow(true)
#18 /app/code/community/Aoe/Scheduler/Model/Observer.php(39): Aoe_Scheduler_Model_Schedule->process()
#19 /app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/App.php(1339): Aoe_Scheduler_Model_Observer->dispatch(Object(Varien_Event_Observer))
#20 /app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/App.php(1318): Mage_Core_Model_App->_callObserverMethod(Object(Aoe_Scheduler_Model_Observer), 'dispatch', Object(Varien_Event_Observer))
#21 /app/Mage.php(448): Mage_Core_Model_App->dispatchEvent('default', Array)
#22 /shell/scheduler.php(377): Mage::dispatchEvent('default', Array)
#23 /shell/scheduler.php(37): Aoe_Scheduler_Shell_Scheduler->cronAction()
#24 /shell/scheduler.php(403): Aoe_Scheduler_Shell_Scheduler->run()
#25 {main}";s:11:"script_name";s:13:"scheduler.php";s:4:"skin";s:5:"admin";}
```

In MailChimp_Errors.log file there is nothing. I think this could be some product or order that is missing something. I would like to know which product or order is causing this kind of error to fix it, because it can happen again. How can I find which one is causing this error? Any help will be extremely appreciated.

Comment: how you do manully sync reply plz

Answer (score 0):

Looks like the actual error message is missing there.
Anyways looking at the query seems to be when processing the products. You can place a log in order to find the one breaking the process.

In order to do this just go to [this line](https://github.com/mailchimp/mc-magento/blob/master/app/code/community/Ebizmarts/MailChimp/Model/Api/Products.php#L38) and add the log as follows:
`Mage::log($product->getEntityId(), null, 'product.log', true);`

The next time the ecommerce cron job runs it will create a log file called product.log at your Magento's var/log folder showing all the ids it processes, the last one should be the troubling one.

Regards.